# for loop doing weird things python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-imaging-library

I wrote a little code to *try* to create an image with only one black dot per Y-value, but it creates more then one per Y-value. The image -> [image: the output image]

the image is small, but you can see that there can be more than one black dot per Y-value. The actual code:

```
from PIL import Image
from random import *
from math import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

width = 50
height = 10
num = 0
def line(num):
    mylist = []
    a = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    for row in xrange(width):
        dot = False
        for col in xrange(height):
            rand = random()
            b = float(col)/(width-1)
            if b > rand and not dot:
                mylist.append(black)
                dot = True
            else:
                mylist.append(white)
    a.putdata(mylist)
    a.save("boop"+str(num)+".png")

line(num)
```

Normally when it appends a black dot, `dot` becomes true, so there can't be another black dot before the next row of pixels.  Why isn't this working?

EDIT: exemple of desired output ->[image: desired output]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Where is the output from your debugging traces?  If nothing else, you should insert a couple of strategically-placed `print` statements and dump the points as you generate them.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Maybe use `continue` in your `for` loop when you find a black dot? What is the purpose of the random number? It seems that your code is set to accept violations of what I understand is your criteria, with some random possibility.

Comment: the random number is there so the black dot has less chance to have a low height (inversed from our perspective since at the top the Y value is 0)

Answer (score 2):

Your row is set for range width and your column is height, change the `xrange(width)` with `xrange(height)` and vice versa then the image should be output as desired.

As it stands, it is checking for 10 columns for a dot as opposed to the 50 it should be looking for.

**EDIT 3**

```
import numpy as np

#other declarations as above#

def line(num):
    mylist = np.zeros((width, height))
    for row in mylist:
        row[randint(0,9)] = 1
    npArr = mylist.T
    a = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    mylist = []
    for idx, val in np.ndenumerate(npArr):
        if val == 1:
            mylist.append(black)
        else:
            mylist.append(white)
    a.putdata(mylist)
    a.save("boop"+str(num)+".png")
```

If you can install numpy, you can create an array, fill it row-wise since you can append a column with a random 1 (dot) in it and then rotate the array to the landscape orientation.

Outputs --> [image]

Comment: I tried playing with which for loop first and all but the order I wrote it in gives the closest desired output, anything else makes matter worse

Comment: I am not saying to change the order of the loops, only to replace the values in the `xrange` call, everything else should stay the same.

Comment: thanks for that answer, I actually think the problem is with the append as the list is read from top left corner to bottom right going right first and as I wrote it, I was adding the the Y-value (top to bottom) then going right on the X-axis

Comment: I added a picture of an exemple of what the output should look like, one dot per X-axis with random Y-axis

Answer (score 0):

so I found what the problem was, the putdata(list) function write from left to right then from top to bottom on the image but my function was trying to append from top to bottom then left to right so it wasnt creating the right output. to fix that, I fill the list with white color (width*height times) then I change the change the color in the list with [col * width + row] formula. the code:

```
width = 50
height = 10
num = 0
mylist = []
def line(num):
    a = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    for pixel in xrange(width*height):
        mylist.append(white)
    for row in xrange(width):
        dot = False
        for col in xrange(height):
            rand1 = random()
            rand2 = random()
            b = float(col)/(height-1)
            if rand1 < b < rand2 and not dot:
                mylist[col*width+row] = black
                dot = True
            if col == height-1 and not dot:
                rand3 = randint(0, height-1)
                mylist[rand3*width+row] = black
    a.putdata(mylist)
    a.save("boop"+str(num)+".png")

line(num)
```

the output -> [image: output]